# CSS Width with Custom Tags

Tags: html, css, custom-tags

I am unable to get the width and heigh properties to work for my custom tags please see code below:
CSS

```
 x-slider
 {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px black solid;    
    background-color: #0000ff;
  }
```

HTML

```
<body><x-slider id="CoolPics" page="home"></x-slider></body>
```

Javascript

```
  var x = document.registerElement('x-slider', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype), extends: 'div'
});
```

I added the Extension of the DIV object to see if that would allow me to specify heigh since some tags do not allow for height.  Is it only certain css properties that work with custom tags? Both the border and background color show up, I have tried changing over to both min and max height as well.  Please limit response to the question and not the subjective argument of whether you should use custom tags, It made it significantly harder to search for answer for this with every post about custom tags overloaded with those kinda of responses.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the purpose of you using a "custom tag".

Comment: Custom tags have various purposes especially in api's.  They make code easier to follow than having big complicated div structures with lots of CSS on them.  If your coding for someone else instead of yourself who doesn't need to know how everything exactly works this can be a huge boon.  I only asked for no answers like this because it is a highly subjective and hot argument topic and I wanted others to be able to look up the answer to this question without sifting through the argument posts as I had too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to `x-slider`.

Comment: I think you meant “or `display: inline-block`”.

Comment: The reason why this helps is that “custom tags” are by default inline elements (with `display: inline`).

Comment: Thank you I wrongly assumed the having it inherit from a div would take care of this.